# Using RDFa meta property with facebook's XHP

Tags: php, xhtml, rdf

I'm playing with [xhp](/questions/tagged/xhp) and I  got stuck on this:

```
echo <meta property="og:title" content="page title" />;
```

It throws:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'XHPAttributeNotSupportedException' with message 'Attribute `property` is not supported in class `meta`.
```

I understand why - it's not valid XHTML 1.0. Property and content attributes comes from RDFa 1.0 spec.

What can I do to use such literals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this 2-years later, the  tag is now a candidate recommendation for HTML5 ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta ), and XHP has chosen to only support the HTML5 doctype (). In short, XHP now includes  support. If you're seeing this error, you simply need your XHP updated.

Comment: No, aside from currently being tagged 'unimplemented', that's not what sites like Facebook will check. The tag you gave in your original example should work just fine.